# How to programmatically get a steam app's clienticon hash

Tags: c#, steam, steam-web-api

I've been trying to find a way to get steam's hash for a particular app's clienticon (The clienticon field on [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/app/1968730/info/), not just the regular icon) in C#. To do this, I've used C# [processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0) to access CMD and dump the output to a txt.

I have tried doing this from cmd making use of steamCMD, as client icon hash can be optained using app_info_print, but this results in an incomplete result.
`steamcmd +app_info_update 1382070 +app_info_print 1382070 +quit 1> _output.txt 2>&1`

returns:
Redirecting stderr to 'C:\shit\SteamCMD\logs\stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation - version 1689642531
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam API...OK

With "No app info for AppID 1382070 found, requesting..." on the end half the time.

Sorry if the answer is obvious, any help would be appreciated